# The problem “Fun game” from a competition

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, array

I recently began to learn Python and encountered this problem.

**The condition:**
You and your friends are playing the next game. Friends write  natural numbers in a row on the board. Your task is to find as many consecutive numbers as possible that are divisible by the same number greater than `1`. Since it is difficult to find the answer manually, you decided to write a program that will do the job for you.

**Input:**
The first line of the input contains the number  (`1 ≤  ≤ 100000`). The second line is separated by a space  integers `1`... (`1 ≤  ≤ 1000`, `1 ≤  ≤` ). These are the numbers that your friends wrote. They are given in the same order as they are placed on the board.

**Output:**
Your program should output a single integer — the largest number of consecutive numbers in a given sequence that would be divisible by the same natural number greater than `1`.

**Here is my code:**

```
Python
    
from math import gcd

def func(n,a):

    mx = 0
    for i, cur_g in enumerate(a):
        if n - i < mx:
            break
        p = 0
        for j in range(i, n):
            cur_g = gcd(cur_g, a[j])
            if cur_g == 1:
                break
            p += 1
            if mx < p:
                mx = p

    return mx

print(func(int(input()), [int(i) for i in input().split()]))
```

The problem is that I can't pass the time check: the program runs for longer than 0.5 seconds. And I can't think of any way to speed up the program. It may even be necessary to solve the problem itself in a different way. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The way your loops are organized results in an unpleasant phenomenon. Namely, you process the same subsequence many times. Let's say, a long good range starts at the index `k` and has a length `n`. The inner loop finds it. Then the next iteration of the outer loop starts processing it again, this time from index `k + 1`. Then from index `k+2`, etc. It will take \$O(n^2)\$ of unnecessary computations. In fact, each good range contributes a term quadratic to its length to the total complexity.

The fix is, once the inner loop terminated, adjust `i` to continue from the number which broke the good range.

Comment: Thank you for your decision, I understand it, but I can't implement it. Please help me.